# How to properly use recursion on nested lists in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am 4 weeks into programming with python and now we are talking about recursion.

### Problem statement

I need to write a function with one parameter which is a list; the function must check if the list and its sublists satisfy the criteria:

- all elements in the list are ints;

**OR**

- all elements in the list are lists,
- **AND** all sublists also satisfy the criteria.

For example:

```
[1, 2]                 True
[[1, 2, [1]]]          False
[[1], [2], [[3], [1]]] True
```

And so on.

### My attempt so far

I tried to check the width first and then go into the depth. Go level per level deeper.
But this wont work because at some point this

```
[[1], [2], [[3], [1]]]
```

goes to

```
1, 2, [3], [1]
```

which is wrong.

I realised i need to go into the depth first and if I can't go deeper and checked everything I need to go back. Something like a binary tree. And there is my problem. I don't know when I am deep and finished to come back to my "leftover" list.

```py
def intSuperListe(list_to_check):
    for idx, item in enumerate(list_to_check):
        if idx + 1 < len(list_to_check):
            if type(list_to_check[idx]) == type(list_to_check[idx + 1]):
                if type(list_to_check[idx]) == int:
                    if len(list_to_check) == 1 or len(list_to_check) == 2:
                        return True
                    else:
                        continue
                elif type(list_to_check[idx]) == list:
                    intSuperListe(list_to_check[idx])
                return True
            return False
        elif type(list_to_check[idx]) == int:
            return True
        elif type(list_to_check[idx]) == list:
            intSuperListe(list_to_check[idx])
            break
        else:
            return False
```

This was my try.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You will need to go breadth first, not depth. You will need to see that *all* elements are either lists or ints before you check any of the lists present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to write code which mirrors the requirements:

Return `True` if all items in a list are `int`s.

Return `True` if all items in a list are `list`s and those sublists are also compliant.

Else return `False`

```py
def intSuperListe(list_to_check):
    areInts = all(isinstance(item, int) for item in list_to_check)
    if areInts:
        return True

    areLists = all(isinstance(item, list) for item in list_to_check)
    if areLists:
        return all(intSuperListe(item) for item in list_to_check)

    return False


for item in [[1, 2], [[1, 2, [1]]], [[1], [2], [[3], [1]]]]:
    print(intSuperListe(item), item)
```

Output:

```
True [1, 2]
False [[1, 2, [1]]]
True [[1], [2], [[3], [1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def intSuperListe(list_to_check):
    if all(map(lambda x:isinstance(x, int), list_to_check)):
        return True
    elif all(map(lambda x:isinstance(x, list), list_to_check)):
        return all(map(intSuperListe, list_to_check))
    return False
```

```py
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [[1, 2, [1]]]
>>> c = [[1], [2], [[3], [1]]]
>>> print(intSuperListe(a))
True
>>> print(intSuperListe(b))
False
>>> print(intSuperListe(c))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def intSuperListe(lst):

    if all([type(l) == int for l in lst]):
        # if all elements of lst are ints then this is True
        return True
    elif all([type(l) == list for l in lst]):
        # if all elements of lst are lists, recursively check
        # all elements by calling intSuperListe on each
        return all([intSuperListe(l) for l in lst])
    else:
        # If all elements are not list or ints, then return
        # False
        return False


a = [1, 2]
b = [[1, 2, [1]]]
c = [[1], [2], [[3], [1]]]

print(intSuperListe(a))
print(intSuperListe(b))
print(intSuperListe(c))

>>> True
>>> False
>>> True
```